# How to generate tables using Identity 2.0 from custom models?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my project I use asp.net mvc 5 Identity 2.0 .

First time when I run the project in my DB has been created all default tables for authentication and authorization:

[image]

Now I create my custom model:

```
    public class TestMigration
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string column1 { get; set; }
        public int column2 { get; set; }
    }
```

and I want to create  testMigration table.So first I declare testMigration in ApplicationDbContext:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public testMigration ()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestMigration> testMigration { get; set; }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

And I try to generate TestMigration table using **Add-Migration** and **Update-Database** command.

After I run **Update-Database** command, I get this massage in Package Manager Console:

```
There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database.
```

It seems that it try to generate again all default authentication and authorization tables when I try to create testMigration table.

So my question is how to generate my custom tables?
And how can I generate custom tales and prevent to generate again authentication and authorization tables?

Comment: first apply this command `Add-Migration TestMigration ` and check generated file containing `UP` and `down` method  than do some changes and than `Update-Database –Verbose`

Comment: @Curiousdev , thanks for comment.Can you please give brief explanation about Update-Database –Verbose commnad?